# I did a git pull origin <featurename> on develop which is not what I wanted to do

Tags: git

I wanted to bring a branch from remote to my local machine for that I used `git pull origin <featurename>` on `develop branch`. All I wanted to do was to get the new branch but I've got `(develop|MERGING)`. I would like to undo my git pull origin  command. As I don't want to do anything on develop branch.

Answer (score 1):

To undo what you've done:

```
git merge --abort
```

Then I think what you meant to do was:

```
git checkout <featurename>
```

Comment: thanks the git merge --abort helped. I then did a git fetch and finally got the branch on my local machine.